# node.js does not register requests from browser but postman

Tags: node.js, express, fetch, http-headers

i have node.js express server. i'm trying to send request from front-end which is running on `http://localhost:3000` but it gives me Cors error

```
const express = require("express");
require('dotenv').config({ path: `./env/.env.${process.env.NODE_ENV}` })
const app = require('./src/routes')
const cors = require('cors')
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser')
app.use(express.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.use(cookieParser())
app.use(cors({
    origin: ['http://localhost:3000'],
    methods: ['GET', 'POST', 'DELETE', 'UPDATE', 'PUT', 'PATCH']
}))

const PORT = process.env.PORT || 5000;
const hostname = '0.0.0.0';

app.listen(PORT, hostname, () => console.log(`server running on ${hostname}:${PORT}`));
```

it works perfectly from postman and server logs it shows that new request has arrived. but when i send from browser it does not even reach to backend.

Answer (score 0):

Use this

```
app.use((req, res, next) => {
  res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
  next();
});
```

However, this is not recommended for production environments as it can introduce security vulnerabilities.
You can also try adding the Access-Control-Allow-Origin header to your responses. This header allows the browser to access resources from a different origin

Comment: Does not work. same cors error. i have already tried all method i found on stackoverflow

Comment: can you mention what the error is basically

Comment: If you are running your backend server on a different domain or port than your frontend application, you might need to configure CORS settings on your server to allow requests from the frontend domain

Comment: or Make sure that your browser is not blocking the request due to security settings or browser extensions. Try disabling any security or firewall software that might be blocking your requests, and try using a different browser to see if the issue persists

Comment: i was defining cors after routes. so i fixed it. thanks guys.